# PHP - Как в отсортированных элементах массива вынести названия элементов

Tags: php

На Opencart 3 на странице корзины отображаются товары, которые туда поставил пользователь. Стоит задача отсортировать эти товары по производителю и вынести название производителя отдельно. Чтобы получились подгруппы. Выглядеть примерно должно так.

```
Название производителя 1
Товар 1
Товар 2
Товар 3

Название производителя 2
Товар 5
Товар 6
Товар 7
```

На данный момент с помощью usort удалось отсортировать все товары по производителям

```
usort($data['products'], function($a, $b) {
    return $a['manufacturer'] <=> $b['manufacturer'];
});
```

В итоге получаю нужную сортировку. Массив приходит в том порядке, в котором нужно. Только как теперь название магазинов ['manufacturer'] выделить в отдельное название, чтобы получилось на примере как выше?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cart_id] => 23
            [thumb] => http://magis.loc/image/cache/catalog/Products/shoe3-90x90.jpg
            [name] => Кроссовки мужские белые для повседневной носки
            [model] => 
            [upc] => 8
            [manufacturer] => Bykilian
            [manufacturers] => http://magis.loc/index.php?route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=12
            [option] => Array
                (
                )

            [recurring] => 
            [quantity] => 2
            [stock] => 1
            [reward] => 
            [price] => 179.00 $
            [total] => 358.00 $
            [href] => http://magis.loc/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=52
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cart_id] => 26
            [thumb] => http://magis.loc/image/cache/catalog/Products/shoe4-90x90.jpg
            [name] => Бутсы спортивные мужские
            [model] => 36 - 1 шт
            [upc] => 8
            [manufacturer] => Bykilian
            [manufacturers] => http://magis.loc/index.php?route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=12
            [option] => Array
                (
                )

            [recurring] => 
            [quantity] => 2
            [stock] => 1
            [reward] => 
            [price] => 80.00 $
            [total] => 160.00 $
            [href] => http://magis.loc/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=53
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [cart_id] => 29
            [thumb] => http://magis.loc/image/cache/catalog/Products/shoe5-90x90.jpg
            [name] => Кроссовки мужские для повседневной носки
            [model] => 
            [upc] => 8
            [manufacturer] => Kidsnail
            [manufacturers] => http://magis.loc/index.php?route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=13
            [option] => Array
                (
                )

            [recurring] => 
            [quantity] => 2
            [stock] => 1
            [reward] => 
            [price] => 194.00 $
            [total] => 388.00 $
            [href] => http://magis.loc/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=54
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [cart_id] => 24
            [thumb] => http://magis.loc/image/cache/catalog/Products/shoe7-90x90.jpg
            [name] => Туфли женские открытые
            [model] => 
            [upc] => 8
            [manufacturer] => Longstormaier
            [manufacturers] => http://magis.loc/index.php?route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=11
            [option] => Array
                (
                )

            [recurring] => 
            [quantity] => 4
            [stock] => 1
            [reward] => 
            [price] => 199.00 $
            [total] => 796.00 $
            [href] => http://magis.loc/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=56
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [cart_id] => 25
            [thumb] => 
            [name] => Туфли женские на каблуке
            [model] => 
            [upc] => 6
            [manufacturer] => Longstormaier
            [manufacturers] => http://magis.loc/index.php?route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=11
            [option] => Array
                (
                )

            [recurring] => 
            [quantity] => 3
            [stock] => 1
            [reward] => 
            [price] => 150.00 $
            [total] => 450.00 $
            [href] => http://magis.loc/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=51
        )



)
```

Так выглядит функция по умолчанию, которая выводит массив

```
            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product['product_id']);
                $product_total = 0;
    

                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'cart_id'   => $product['cart_id'],
                    'thumb'     => $image,
                    'name'      => $product['name'],
                    'model'     => $product['model'],
                    'upc'     => $product_info['upc'],
                    'manufacturer'     => $product_info['manufacturer'],
                    'manufacturers'    => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $product_info['manufacturer_id']),
                    'option'    => $option_data,
                    'recurring' => $recurring,
                    'quantity'  => $product['quantity'],
                    'stock'     => $product['stock'] ? true : !(!$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout') || $this->config->get('config_stock_warning')),
                    'reward'    => ($product['reward'] ? sprintf($this->language->get('text_points'), $product['reward']) : ''),
                    'price'     => $price,
                    'total'     => $total,
                    'href'      => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'])
                );
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перестройте массив

```
$res = [];

foreach ($data['products'] as $x) {
   $res[$x['manufacturer']][] = $x;
}

foreach ($res as $k=>$v) {
   // $k - производитель 
   foreach ($v as $x) { 
        // $x - товар
   }
}
```

Comment: Массив перестроился. Производитель вышел на верхний уровень. Все хорошо. Спасибо. Застрял теперь на выводе во фронтэнд. До этого в TWIG получал данные так: `{% for product in products %}`. И каждый элемент так: `{{ product.name }}`. Теперь, если пишу `{% for res in products %}`, могу получить элемент так: `{{ res.name }}`. А как получать производителя, который название группы товаров на верхнем уровне? Что-то не доходит((

Comment: не знаю twig, но что-то типа  {% for manufacturer, res in products %} {{ manufacturer }}

Comment: ну да, Iterating over Keys and Values
  вот тут https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html

Comment: Где то не там я свернул. Он мне дает обычные номера товаров, которые должны быть в оригинальном массиве. Подскажите пожалуйста как бы вы вывели эти данные во фронтэнд через обычный PHP? Может тогда увижу свою ошибку.

Comment: второй foreach - это как раз вывод. Подставьте echo в первом случае и print_r во втором

Comment: Это я уже понял, а то я сначала к первому делал. Только не могу сообразить куда print_r во втором делать. Прошу прощения, в php еще новичок. Только учусь.

Comment: Я делаю print_r($res); под этим всем, и получаю массив, который нужен. Встрял, как из этого массива данные вытащить в стиле Производитель 1 - товар 1,  товар 2. Производитель 2 - товар 3, товар 4 итд.

Comment: Внес изменения в вопрос, добавил функцию, которая выводит массив.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$products = [
    ['manufacturer' => 'Nike', 'name' => 'Кроссовки мужские'],
    ['manufacturer' => 'Nike', 'name' => 'Кроссовки женские'],
    ['manufacturer' => 'Puma', 'name' => 'Штаны мужские'],
    ['manufacturer' => 'Puma', 'name' => 'Штаны женские'],
];

$manufacturerToProducts = [];
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $manufacturer = $product['manufacturer'];
    $manufacturerToProducts[$manufacturer][] = $product;
}

foreach ($manufacturerToProducts as $manufacturer => $products) {
    echo "\n{$manufacturer}:\n";
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo "\t{$product['name']}\n";
    }
}
```

Этот скрипт выведет:

```
Nike:
        Кроссовки мужские
        Кроссовки женские

Puma:
        Штаны мужские
        Штаны женские
```

Даже не обязательно, чтобы массив $products был отсортированным.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Не понял как с этим работать. Я только учусь PHP. Возможно с моей стороны не хватало данных. Добавил в описание функцию, которая выводит массив. Может это поможет?